# shopify webhook call based on landing page query parameters

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

I am new to shopify and working on an app to track referrals from my website (not a shopify site). The app will be installed by the shopify store owner.

I created a webhook to track orders and it gets all the order requests. However, I would like the webhook to be called only if the landing page had a certain query parameter (indicating that it is a referral from my site). Otherwise, I would be getting all orders not just the ones originated from my site. Is there a way to do this at shopify?

I would be grateful for any pointers you might have.

Thanks,

Doug